# Bluetooth audio stutters every 10-30 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, a2dp

I am having issues with Bluetooth on Windows 10. When I connect either my [Sony WH-H900N headphones](https://www.sony.com/electronics/headband-headphones/wh-h900n/specifications) or my Sony Bluetooth speaker, every 10-30 seconds the audio stutters for a second or two.

I have tried numerous things, Updating Bluetooth drivers, audio and sound drivers, systematically disabling drivers, re-pairing devices. I am at a loss. Any help will be appreciated.

Hardware setup is:

- **CPU** - Ryzen 2700x
- **GPU** - Vega 64
- **MEM** - 16g DDR4 3200MHZ
- **MOBO** - [ASUS B450-I](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-B450-I-GAMING/) (Has Bluetooth built-in)
- **HDD** - Samsung m2 970

Comment: Do you have any other devices to test? That would rule out a defect in one of the two devices.

Comment: I managed to solve the issue by downloading a general 'driver installer' tool. They scan your hardware and install various drivers. Not to sure what driver it installed but it worked.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to share my resolution as well since it was different than yours. Funny enough we have almost identical systems, I have an ASRock Fatal1ty AB350 Gaming-ITX/ac motherboard with built-in Bluetooth as well.

**My solution was to reconnect the Wi-Fi antennas** to the ports on the back I/O panel. I had removed them as I was using an Ethernet cable and had no need for them but it turns out the motherboard is using these antennae for Bluetooth reception.

I had only realized this because I wore my headphones while the sound was stuttering and the reception was terrible once I left my desk. I remembered it used to have a much larger range previously.

I'm hoping this helps, I tried uninstalling / re-installing and re-configuring all my devices to not avail.

Comment: OMG! Thank you! I just spent over an hour trying to figure out what the issue was. I built my computer myself, I have an asus pro tuf x570 pro wifi and i didn't bother with the antenna because I'm setting right next to the computer and I'm connected via LAN cable. I connected the antenna and now the bluetooth is flawless! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and nearly checked out every answer that was to it. It is primarily because of your WiFi and Bluetooth using the same frequency, which is 2.4 GHz. Well some suggested that I buy a Bluetooth USB adapter for a tenner or so, but that beats the whole purpose of having a laptop with great specs as well as overall convenience.

Solution: I got a new router, Dual-band, capable of both 2.4 as well as 5gHz. I turned off the 2.4gHz broadcast from my router settings and everything works now.
As an added bonus my internet even works better now thanks to the 5gHz channel.
I am in no way sour over the reason that I had to buy a new router to resolve this issue, because of all these new mbits lol.

Go for it!

Answer (score -1):

If your router is controlling wifi but your windows 10 wifi is enabled, turn the Win10 Wifi off in settings.  BT and WiFi share frequencies and sometimes conflict.  If it works, post your result, please.

Comment: Can you explain how this works?  It seems like, if you’re using Wi-Fi and you turn it off, you’ll lose network connectivity. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score -1):

This solution worked for me. Hope it works for you too.

1. Press the Windows key and start typing "control panel" to find the icon to open the Control Panel. (As of the time of writing, Windows 10 does not have a way to change this setting via the new 'Settings' interface.)
2. Find 'Devices and Printers' and double-click it.
3. Find your paired headphones. The icon may not look like your headphones, but hopefully you should be able to find it.
4. Right-click the icon and select 'Properties'.
5. Select the 'Services' tab at the top.
6. Under 'Bluetooth Services', if 'Hands-free Telephony' is checked, uncheck it.
   Click OK.

Reference:
https://www.madwebskills.com/article/!/29/post/fixing-stuttering-audio-with-bluetooth-headphones-on-windows-10